# How do I write a watchdog daemon in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, daemon, nohup

I want a way to write a daemon in a shell script, which runs another application in a loop, restarting it if it dies.

- When run using `./myscript.sh` from an SSH session, it shall launch a new instance of the daemon, except if the daemon is already running.
- When the SSH session ends, the daemon shall persist.
- There shall be a parameter (`./myscript -stop`) that kills any existing daemon.

---

(***Notes on edit*** - The original question specified that `nohup` and similar tools may not be used. This artificial requirement was an "XY question", and the accepted answer in fact uses all the tools the OP claimed were not possible to use.)

Comment: Why do you need the pid? That sounds a little suspect: to have a daemon process, you need to do the double-fork trick (fork/setsid/fork). That means that the launching process, although it could have the pid of the grandchild sent to it, can't wait on the daemon. There isn't really much use for the pid of a daemon (the daemon itself could use it, of course, to put in /var/run for example and make sure it's the only copy of itself running).

Comment: @NicholasWilson If the PID we get in that trick is no use, could you please give me an example of the version you said? Because i have seen that trick awhile ago and cannot remember much details now. I need PID exactly to avoid dup. proccess. So the main proc will receive args like start, stop, etc, and forked should work as watchdog for another proc there. I have no problem with watchdog and args, but stuck with proper forking

Comment: You'll have to explain that a bit more. You say you want a daemon process, that is, one that's fully detached from whatever launched it. You want another script that can control the daemon. Is it duplicate daemon processes you're trying to avoid? In that case, at the start of your daemon script you should do `if test -f /var/run/appname.pid; then exit; fi; echo $$ > /var/run/appname.pid; trap 'rm /var/run/appname.pid' EXIT`. Then launch the daemon with nohup. To communicate with a daemon, you'll need to use some other mechanism of IPC anyway (bash supports FIFOs).

Comment: @NicholasWilson so what is the general purpose of this script is that it will be called lets say from ssh session like ./my_script.sh then it will fork itself to daemon and as daemon it will start another appname, then run in infinite loop doing checking every second whether that process is alive, if not - restart it. As i mentioned before, i am pretty much aware of nohup, but it is no use in my case, same as no cron is available.

Comment: A little bit more why cannot use nohup for calling this script itself: this script is invoked from another one and checks if it is already running, if not, then it goes to daemon, if yes, it exits leaving daemon running and reports of this situation, if top level script was called with parameter lets say stop -- it will be able to stop this watchdog.

Comment: You have to use nohup, or something equivalent: a daemon *is* a detached process. You have to use some command that will reparent the child to init! disown (a bash builtin) will reparent the child later, when the shell exits. Depending on your needs, you will need some IPC to control the daemon. If all you need is the ability to stop it, then saving its pid is good enough, otherwise, you're down to FIFOs probably (from bash).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on clarifications in comments, what you actually want is a daemon process that keeps a child running, relaunching it whenever it exits. You want a way to type "./myscript.sh" in an ssh session and have the daemon started.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PIDFILE=~/.mydaemon.pid
if [ x"$1" = x-daemon ]; then
  if test -f "$PIDFILE"; then exit; fi
  echo $$ > "$PIDFILE"
  trap "rm '$PIDFILE'" EXIT SIGTERM
  while true; do
    #launch your app here
    /usr/bin/server-or-whatever &
    wait # needed for trap to work
  done
elif [ x"$1" = x-stop ]; then
  kill `cat "$PIDFILE"`
else
  nohup "$0" -daemon
fi
```

Run the script: it will launch the daemon process for you with nohup. The daemon process is a loop that watches for the child to exit, and relaunches it when it does.

To control the daemon, there's a `-stop` argument the script can take that will kill the daemon. Look at examples in your system's init scripts for more complete examples with better error checking.

Comment: Thank you for the script. We just need to start the service with `./myscript.sh -daemon` to prevent 2 concurrent watchdog services running in parallel

Answer (score 2):

The pid of the most recently "backgrounded" process is stored in `$!`

```
$ cat &
[1] 7057
$ echo $!
7057
```

I am unaware of a `fork` command in bash. Are you sure bash is the right tool for this job?

Comment: yes, i am sure. And there is no problem with getting PID of last ran proccess, but it is not same as fork. The purpose of fork is to be able to create a daemon process which will not die after parent process hangs up. Running proc with bg or & (which are same) will not let it continue when invoker will hang up (e.g. you log out from ssh session)

Comment: @AlexKey if you want to leave a process running when you hang up an ssh connection, you need to do two things. 1. disown the process so it will not get a SIGHUP when the shell dies, and 2. redirect all input and output, otherwise ssh may hang waiting for input/output to close. Hence: `cmd </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown`

Comment: @geirha yes, i know how it works in theory and can implement it in C++ for example. But when it comes to bash scripts i am very often stuck at this kind of things. Could you give me code example for this? I tried to google bash fork examples, but everything points to nohup, which is no use in my case.

Comment: @AlexKey, I did: `cmd </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown`