# how to make a shell script watchdog timer to check an other program or hardware is alive?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, watchdog

I need a simple script to reset a peripheral mcu. My need is a loop that should be pinged from the latest. In case of no receiving ping during 2 minutes, the reset-mcu script is launched.

I found a little example to start here : [How do I write a watchdog daemon in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025790/how-do-i-write-a-watchdog-daemon-in-bash) 
and my code seems working. The peripheral can launch shell command.

```
#!/bin/sh
PIDFILE=~/.wd.pid
if [ x"$1" = x-daemon ]; then
#  logger "command daemon"
  sleep 1
  if test -f "$PIDFILE"; then 
   logger "${$} do ping n exit $PIDFILE"
   kill -s SIGUSR1 `cat "$PIDFILE"`
   exit
  fi
  echo $$ > "$PIDFILE"
  trap "rm '$PIDFILE'; logger '"${$}" see you 1'; exit" SIGTERM SIGINT
#  trap "logger '${$} start n stop $PIDFILE'; '$0' ; kill `cat "$PIDFILE"`; exit" SIGUSR1 SIGINT
  trap "logger '${$} start n stop $PIDFILE'; '$0' ; rm '$PIDFILE'; logger '"${$}" see you 2'; exit" SIGUSR1 SIGINT
#  trap "logger 'see you'; exit" EXIT
  while true; do
    #launch your app here
    logger "hello ${$}"
    sleep 120 &
    wait # needed for trap to work
    logger "DO NOT DISPLAY THAT" #timeout wd : this command will be replaced by reset-mcu
  done
elif [ x"$1" = x-stop ]; then
  logger "${$} command stop $PIDFILE"
  kill `cat "$PIDFILE"`
elif [ x"$1" = x-ping ]; then
  logger "${$} command ping $PIDFILE"
  kill -s SIGUSR1 `cat "$PIDFILE"`
else
#  logger "command other"
  "$0" -daemon &
fi
```

My question is : What do you think about this style of coding ? I wonder if I can use less process.

Comment: This is interesting, yet confusing. The question is "How do I do this shell watchdog thing." Then you proceed to give an answer to that question where normally one would better describe the question. Then you ask two more questions at the end, one of which is fairly non-objective. I would love to see you close this and ask two new questions: "Can this script use less processes?" and give detailed functional requirements. And, ask "What are some stylistic changes you would make to this script and why?"